# Alamofire swift library version 4.4 is not installing in swift 3.0.2 project

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to install Alamofire 4.4 in my swift project with pod i am following the step from the given link (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) 
but i am facing this issue:-

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Alamofire (~> 4.4)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Alamofire (~> 4.4)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.
```

I have in in my System : 
 Mac os : 10.12.2
 x_code version : 8.2.1
 swift version : 3.0.2

pod File configuration :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testAlarmofireAndswiftyJson' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for testAlarmofireAndswiftyJson
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

I am stucking here please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute the follwoing on your terminal

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then change pod file configuration to '9.0' to '10.0'

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'project_name' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

After changing the podfile configuration open terminal and go to project path. 
Then execute following

```
'pod install'
```

Comment: I have changed the configuration according to you but still coming same error.

Comment: If  I configure this :

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'project_name' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
end

then its intalled Alamofire v- 3.1.2

Comment: @DHYANCHANDRASINGH : open terminal and fire this command 'pod repo update' then try

Comment: I have already tried this command ( pod repo update) but its continuous (more the 1 hour) showing : -
Updating spec repo `master`
Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance.

can you tell me that how much time it will take.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `source` statement to your Podfile so CocoaPods knows where to search for the pods you're referencing. You likely want this at the top of your Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

> `CocoaPods` 1.1.0+ is required to build `Alamofire` 4.0.0+.

To update `CocoaPods` you simply install the gem again

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

Or for a pre-release version

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

And then try again

Answer (score 0):

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '02-Weibo' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for 02-Weibo

       pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
       pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.2.0'
end
```

---

bash command:

```
appledeMacBook-Pro:Weibo apple$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Installing Alamofire (4.4.0)
Installing SDWebImage (4.0.0)
Installing SVProgressHUD (2.1.2)
Installing SnapKit (3.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Weibo.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 6 dependencies from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.

[!] There are duplicate dependencies on `SnapKit` in `Podfile`:

- SnapKit (~> 3.2.0)
- SnapKit
```

---

you can try bash command :

```
appledeMacBook-Pro:Weibo apple$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.2.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.1

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (3.1.0)
Using Alamofire (4.4.0)
Using SDWebImage (4.0.0)
Using SVProgressHUD (2.1.2)
Using SnapKit (3.2.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 5 dependencies from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
appledeMacBook-Pro:Weibo apple$
```